# Exclude Test case from check style

Tags: android, gradle, checkstyle

I would like to exclude android unit & VTA test cases and its related files from checkStyle.I did surf few and unable to solve. Kindly help to do exclude files. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'd do

```
checkstyleMain.configure {
   exclude '**/com/package1/**'
}
checkstyleTest.configure {
   exclude '**/com/package2/**'
}
```

Or perhaps

```
tasks.withType(Checkstyle).configureEach {
   exclude '**/com/package1/**'
   exclude '**/com/package2/**'
}
```

See [Checkstyle.exclude(...)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.Checkstyle.html#org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.Checkstyle:exclude(java.lang.String%5B%5D))